# what's the meaning of "kicked off" in this paragraph

Tags: meaning-in-context

Battles between British troops and colonial
militiamen in Lexington and Concord in April 1775
kicked off the armed conflict, and by the following
summer, the rebels were conducting a full-scale war
for their independence

Answer (score 1):

Literally "initiated", that is, "started off".

It's idiomatic, the metaphor being the "kick-off" of a football ("soccer") match. "Kick off" is when the team who won the toss are first to "kick" (that is, to prod with a boot) the ball into play.